# Expressions about algorithm complexity

Tags: big-o, complexity-theory, proof

I would like to know ways to prove it. Because I have no idea:

n + log n  is Θ(n);

100n is Ω(n2) ;
f(n) is O(f(n/2));

For the two functions g(n) and f(n).f(n)=Ω(g(n)) If and only if f(n)=O(g(n)).

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.
You might want to ask this question on https://cs.stackexchange.com/ instead, but check the help pages there first.

Comment: You can use Omega, Big O and Theta notations in computational complexity theory to prove them. An example: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation